# How to match the variables to my html form to php

Tags: php, html

I have a html form and use the get method

I want to input the data to shoes_sales.txt if the user select shoes option value, and input all the rest to clothes_sales.txt. Unfortunately this data does not show up in my `.txt`.

This is the html form:

```
 <li class="form-line" id="id_16">
   <label class="form-label-left" id="label_16" for="input_16"> Select choice </label>
   <div id="cid_16" class="form-input">
     <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="input_16" name="q16_selectFrom16">
       <option value="Shoes"> Shoes </option>
       <option value="Clothes"> Clothes </option>

     </select>
   </div>
 </li>
```

This is the php trying to retrieve the form values:

```
<?php
  header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");

  if ($_GET['variable1'] == "shoes") {
    $handle = fopen("shoes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  else {
    $handle = fopen("clothes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable."=".$value."\r\n");
  }
  fclose($handle);
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: Put the `header` redirect at the end; it might be redirecting the user before it even starts writing the text files.

Comment: I think this `header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");` will redirect immediately even before your script attempts at writing to your file. Try taking it out or use `echo "Thank you";`. Although this is not tested and I have no time for testing right now. Try putting it under `fclose($handle);` instead, but that could cause a `headers already sent` error message.

Comment: @andrewsi You beat me to it by 11 seconds lol!

Comment: First question is why do you need a header line at the beginning? Second, "variable1" doesn't exist, is that a hidden field you missed? Third, are you using post or get method? if you post you will get nothing in $_GET

Comment: You should also check to see if the files are being opened correctly, too - you're just assuming that they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

  if($_GET['q16_selectFrom16'] )
  {
  if ($_GET['q16_selectFrom16'] == "Shoes") {
    $handle = fopen("shoes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  else {
    $handle = fopen("clothes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    echo $variable;

    $fwrite = fwrite($handle, $variable."=".$value."\r\n");
    if ($fwrite === false) {
            header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");
        }else
        {
          echo "Erorr";
        }
  }
  fclose($handle);
  exit;
  }
?>
<form action="" method="get">
<li class="form-line" id="id_16">
   <label class="form-label-left" id="label_16" for="input_16"> Select choice </label>
   <div id="cid_16" class="form-input">
     <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="input_16" name="q16_selectFrom16">
       <option value="Shoes"> Shoes </option>
       <option value="Clothes"> Clothes </option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="sss" />
   </div>
 </li>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The value in the `$_GET` variable does not correspond to the `name` property currently:

```
$_GET['variable1']
```

should be

```
$_GET['q16_selectFrom16']
```

You're also checking `== "shoes"` and `== "clothes"`, while your values in your `option`s use capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the code you are using

```
header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");
```

Put it at the end of the file, so every lines of code are executed before redirection.

Change this:

```
if ($_GET['variable1'] == "shoes")
```

to

```
if ($_GET['q16_selectFrom16'] == "shoes")
```

and the change text in value tag in options, from

```
<option value="Shoes"> Shoes </option>
<option value="Clothes"> Clothes </option>
```

to

```
<option value="shoes"> Shoes </option>
<option value="clothes"> Clothes </option>
```

for case-sensitivity. It may not be problem, but it is better way.